# Difference between "Convert.ToString(Nullable<int>)" and "Nullable<int>.ToString()"?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, resharper, tostring

i have a generally question about the conversion method ".ToString()".
At first i use this statement for the conversion:

```
Nullable<int> SomeProperty;
string test = SomeProperty.ToString();
```

Up to here there is no problem but after that i want to add "CultureInfo.InvariantCulture" to the ToString() method. It doesn't work because the .ToString() of a Nullable has no parameters. Why does Resharper suggest to insert the CultureInfo informations to me??

After that i try a other way and use this statement:

```
Nullable<int> SomeProperty;
string test = Convert.ToString(SomeProperty, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This statement works fine but now i want to understand the technical difference between the first and the second statement??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Convert.ToString Method (Object, IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131014.aspx):

> If the value parameter implements the IConvertible interface, the
>   method calls the IConvertible.ToString(IFormatProvider) implementation
>   of value. Otherwise, if the value parameter implements the
>   IFormattable interface, the method calls its
>   IFormattable.ToString(String, IFormatProvider) implementation. If
>   value implements neither interface, the method calls the value
>   parameter's ToString() method.

`Nullable<int>` is *seen* like standard `int`, and `IFormattable.ToString(String, IFormatProvider)` is fired when `Convert.ToString` with format provider is called.

Proof:

```
class MyFormatProvider : IFormatProvider
{

    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        return "G";
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Nullable<int> SomeProperty = 1000000;
    Console.WriteLine(SomeProperty.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(SomeProperty));
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(SomeProperty, new MyFormatProvider()));
}
```

Put breakpoint within `GetFormat` and it's going to be hit when the last one of `Main` is executed.

Comment: [`int` implements `IFormattable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx), so this is wrong, this is not going to call `ToString()`, this is going to call `ToString(IFormatProvider)`.

Comment: But it's not about `int`, its about `Nullable<int>`

Comment: A boxed `Nullable<int>` is a boxed `int`. `Convert.ToString` cannot tell that it originally came from a nullable type.

Comment: @hvd: You're right! Just tested it and `IFormattable.ToString(String, IFormatProvider)` is being called! Updated my answer.

Comment: so internally the Convert.ToString() only ignore that the value which i put in is a possible null value?

Answer (score 0):

read msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t7dwaa5.aspx

The return value is formatted with the general numeric format specifier ("G") and the NumberFormatInfo object for the current culture.